# Replace transparent bg with white PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I have an image in php generated like so:

```
$base = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_GET['imgSRC']));
imagepalettetotruecolor($base);
$background = imagecolorallocate($base, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($base, $background);
imagealphablending($base, false);
imagesavealpha($base, true);
```

The image has a transparent background, I would like to replace any transparent pixels with white. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing any of that code. The only line that makes sense is the first one. After that... if you want to replace transparency with white then you clearly *don't* want to set `imagesavealpha`. Likewise, you want `imagealphablending` on to ensure partially-transparent pixels (if any) are handled appropriately.

Comment: Doing this: https://pastebin.com/ACJMV709 results in issues as I am overlaying a second transparent image on top.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a solid image and copying the transparent image over it worked for me:

```
class Solid {
    static function white() {
        return new self(255, 255, 255);
    }

    function __construct($red, $green, $blue) {
        $this->red = $red;
        $this->green = $green;
        $this->blue = $blue;
    }

    function under($pic) {
        $w = imagesx($pic);
        $h = imagesy($pic);

        $buffer = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        imagefilledrectangle($buffer, 0, 0, $w, $h,
            imagecolorallocate($buffer, $this->red, $this->green, $this->blue));

        imagecopy($buffer, $pic, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
$solid_picture = Solid::white()->under($transparent_picture);
```

In case your picture has an alpha channel, consider using `imagecopymerge()` instead of `imagecopy`.